# Change the font color of Types?

Tags: java, types, colors, editor

I come from a visual studios background where types in C#, C++, and VB were all a different color than identifiers. But it seems to me that java considers types (i.e class names) as identifiers and are therefore colored the same. Ive tried changing the settings in both Eclipse and NetBeans but it would just change the color of both types and identifiers. Is there any solution or editor that has types colored differently from identifiers?

Comment: That's because class names are keywords. For example, if you define a class as "public class Person{ }" then typing "Person" in the IDE will refer to that class.

Comment: @Arman If a class name is a keyword shouldn't they be colored as a keyword?

Comment: Well, it actually depends on the context. Like "int Person = 5" will work, but if you just type "Person ... " then the IDE will assume you're referring to the class.

Comment: But all the editors I've tried don't show a different color for it class names which is what I'm looking for. For example "Person foo = new Person();" the color of the word Person would appear the same color as foo, but I'd like to make it such that Person is a different  color like blue, while foo remains white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring, then inside of the dropdown menu select "Classes" and check "Enable" There you can change the color. I think that's the most you can change.